# start nginx fail use bat file in Win8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, batch-file, nginx, mariadb

Here is my .bat file.

```
@echo "start or stop nginx,mysql service"
@echo "1.start DB"
@echo "2.stop DB"
@echo "3.start nginx"
@echo "4.stop nginx"
@echo "5.quit"
@echo off
:choose
set /p st="Choose："
if /i "%st%"=="1" goto open_as
if /i "%st%"=="2" goto close_as
if /i "%st%"=="3" goto open_nm
if /i "%st%"=="4" goto close_nm
if /i "%st%"=="5" goto exit
:open_as
net start MariaDB
goto choose
:close_as
net stop MariaDB
goto choose
:open_nm
@echo "start Nginx....................."
start d:\server\nginx\nginx
@echo "startFastCGI..................."
start d:\Server\RunHiddenConsole d:\server\php5.3.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
d:\server\memcached -d start
goto choose
:close_nm
taskkill /f /im nginx.exe
taskkill /f /im php-cgi.exe
d:\server\memcached -d stop
goto choose
:exit
pause && exit
```

This file work correct in Win7, but it doesn't work in Win8 Pro.

Both MariaDb and memcached are system service. I can start them use "Administrator Mode", but start nginx fail,  and php-cgi.exe start successful. When I am not use "Administrator Mode", both MariaDb and memcached start fail. Nginx and php-cgi.exe start successful.

How do i start them in one Mode?

Comment: you might try adding in "choice /c 1234... /n" after set /p... and before the IF statements this will give the user a choice  if that is what you need to happen here also check with microsoft about some of the parameters. also you can check system 32 for each of the commands to make sure that you did not enter a "fake command"